# How to have all data of one field into an array in case of duplicate row while using left join

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, left-join

I have a resultset associative array like this

```
$result=array(
    array('name'=>'test1','age'=>23,'email'=>'Good'),
    array('name'=>'test2','age'=>24,'email'=>'Good'),
    array('name'=>'test2','age'=>24,'email'=>'Best')
);
```

I need the result like this

```
array(
  0 => 
    array(
      'name' => 'test1',
      'age' => 23,
      'emails' => 
        array (0 => 'Good')
    ),
  1 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'test2',
      'age' => 24,
      'emails' => 
        array (
          0 => 'Good',
          1 => 'Best'
        )
    )
)
```

the other rows should be removed, but one field data should be saved in any of row as I described in the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use group_concat

```
select name, age,  group_concat(emails) as emails
from table
GROUP BY name, age
```

then when you loop your query result, you can explode $row['emails'] by comma and make your array:

```
$arr= array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
$your_internal_arr = explode(',', $row['emails']);
$arr[] = array('name'=> $row['name'], 'age'=> $row['age'], 'emails'=>$your_internal_arr);

}
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Myself got one solution

```
$total_size=sizeof($arr);
for($i=0;$i<$total_size;$i++){
    $arr[$i]['emails']=array();
    $arr[$i]['emails'][]=$arr[$i]['email'];
    $unset=0;
    foreach($arr[$i] as $key=>$value){
        if($key=='name' && $arr[$i]['name']==$arr[$i+1]['name']){
            $arr[$i]['emails'][]=$arr[$i+1]['email'];
            $unset=1;
        }
    }
    unset($arr[$i]['email']);
    if($unset==1){
        unset($arr[$i+1]);
        $i++;
    }
}
```